# Can we define complex path integration in a particular way.

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, complex-integration

Take a curve $z(t) = x(t) + i y(t), a \leq t \leq b$ in the complex plane.

Consider a partition $Q= (a = t_0, t_1, \dots, t_n = b)$ of $[a,b]$.

Associate a partition $P = (z(t_0), \dots, z(t_n))$ and define its norm as

$$N_P := \max_k \{|z_k-z_{k-1}|\}$$

Suppose $f$ is a complex-valued function defined on the curve in the complex plane.  Choose $t_k^* \in [t_{k-1}, t_k]$ and define

$$S_P = \sum_{k=1}^n f(z(t_k^*))(z_k-z_{k-1})$$

My book then gives the following definition:

> If $\lim_{N_P \to 0} S_P$ exists and is independent of the chosen
>   points $t_k^*$, we write $$\int_{z=z(t)} f(z) dz$$ for the limit.

Question:

Does this mean, denoting the limit with $L$:

For all $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that if $P$ is a partition as above with $N_P < \delta$ and if $t_k^*$ is arbitrarily chosen as above, then

$$|S_P - L| < \epsilon$$

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Thank you, you can make that an answer and I'll accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the meaning of integral of $f$ along the curve $z$.